# Type mismatch - Required: Context, Found: Fragment (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, fragment, adapter

I'm having some problem with my app...
I want to see a custom ListView with an image and a text in a Fragment; I've created the Fragment, the single row, the Adapter...but I always get this error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Context
Found: CategoriesFragment
```

This is the code for fragment_categories.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CategoriesFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/titlebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/categories_title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/titlebar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/titlebar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/titlebar" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titlebar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the code for categories_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoriesRowIcon"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoriesRowTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code for CategoriesAdapter.kt:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*

class CategoriesAdapter(var mCtx: Context, var resource:Int, var items:List<Model>)
    :ArrayAdapter<Model>(mCtx,resource,items){

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

        val layoutInflater:LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)

        val view:View = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null)

        val imageView:ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.categoriesRowIcon)
        val textView:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.categoriesRowTitle)

        var mItems:Model = items[position]

        imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.resources.getDrawable(mItems.photo))
        textView.text = mItems.title

        return view
    }

}
```

This is the code for CategoriesFragment.kt:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false)
        var list = mutableListOf<Model>()
        list.add(Model(getString(R.string.history), R.drawable.categories_history))
        list.add(Model(getString(R.string.places), R.drawable.categories_places))
        list.add(Model(getString(R.string.events), R.drawable.categories_events))
        list.add(Model(getString(R.string.recipes), R.drawable.categories_recipes))
        list.add(Model(getString(R.string.shop), R.drawable.categories_shop))
        list.add(Model(getString(R.string.food), R.drawable.categories_food))
        list.add(Model(getString(R.string.sleep), R.drawable.categories_sleep))
        list.add(Model(getString(R.string.contacts), R.drawable.categories_contacts))
        rootView.categories.adapter = CategoriesAdapter(this,R.layout.categories_row,list)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false)
    }
```

Please tell me where I am wrong! Thank you!

Comment: Use requireContext()

Comment: Thank you, now the error is gone, but the ListView is not showing into the Fragment...

Comment: Try requireActivity()

Comment: Even requireActivity() doesn't work...